# Radio button value transfer

Tags: javascript, html, button

The different links of radio buttons, which lead to other pages I coded, should appear after the user selects one radio button and clicks continue. The link of the selected radio button shouldn't open right away, because other information has to be typed in on that page by the user first.

I already included links in the radio button code, but they open right after the selection. So I deleted them from my example code. Also tried getting the value of radio buttons with JavaScript, but I don't know how to transfer it.

```
<!-- begin radio buttons -->
<div class="panel-variation">
    <div class="panel-body"></div>
        <div class="radio-buttons-variation">
            <ul class="radio-buttons-left">
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" name="selection" id="A" value="Hanna">
                    <label>Hanna</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" name="selection" id="B" value="Bryan">
                    <label>Bryan</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" name="selection" id="C" value="Alex">
                    <label>Alex</label>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="radio-buttons-right">
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" name="selection" id="D" value="Gabby">
                    <label>Gabby</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" name="selection" id="E" value="Dan">
                    <label>Dan</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" name="selection" id="F" value="Ryan"> 
                    <label>Ryan</label>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- end radio buttons -->

<!-- begin continue button -->
<div class="buttons">
    <a href="#" class="r7-button">continue</a>
</div>
<!-- end continue button -->
```

```
// getting the selected radio button value 
function select () {
    document.querySelector('input[name="selection"]:checked').value;
}
//transferring value to continue button
?
```

I suppose some JavaScript is needed, which transfers the selection of a radio button as a value to another function related to the continue button. So the radio button link gets opened after the continue button is clicked.

Comment: What do you mean by links of radio buttons?

Comment: I mean reference links like <a href="file.html"></a>. The radio button selection determines which page opens after the continue button gets clicked.

Comment: Well, your contain doesn't contain any links, and even if it did, there is no natural relationship between radio buttons and links. You might want to rephrase your question.

Comment: Unfortunately I had to delete the links, as mentioned in my question. Because the links opened up, as soon as I clicked on the radio buttons, which I want to prevent by using a JS function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to attach a click event listener to your continue button. Inside it's callback function you can check the radio buttons.

To do this, you can use **document.getElementsByName("selection")**, which retuns a **NodeList** - essentially an array - of all the elements having a name of **selection**.
Now simply loop over the array using a for-loop, see if there's an element which's **.checked** property is true and act accordingly.

Here's an example:

```js
function check() {
var found=false;
  var inputElements = document.getElementsByName("selection");
  for (var a = 0; a < inputElements.length; a++) {
    if (inputElements[a].checked) {
      console.log(inputElements[a].value + " is checked!");
      found=true;
      // continue!
    }
  }
  if(!found)
  {
  console.log("nothing selected!");
  }
}
document.getElementsByClassName("r7-button")[0].addEventListener("click", check);
```

```html
<!-- begin radio buttons -->
<div class="panel-variation">
  <div class="panel-body"></div>
  <div class="radio-buttons-variation">
    <ul class="radio-buttons-left">
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="selection" id="A" value="Hanna">
        <label>Hanna</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="selection" id="B" value="Bryan">
        <label>Bryan</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="selection" id="C" value="Alex">
        <label>Alex</label>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="radio-buttons-right">
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="selection" id="D" value="Gabby">
        <label>Gabby</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="selection" id="E" value="Dan">
        <label>Dan</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="selection" id="F" value="Ryan">
        <label>Ryan</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end radio buttons -->

<!-- begin continue button -->
<div class="buttons">
  <a href="#" class="r7-button">continue</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :)

Comment: No problem lu_lu - glad I could help! By the way, if you find this is the correct answer you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `push()` function like so:

```
var answers = [];

// getting the selected radio button value 
function select () {
    var answer = document.querySelector('input[name="selection"]:checked').value;
    answers.push(answer); //transferring value to continue button
}

// Index marks which question it was so answers[0] would be the first question and
 answers[1] would be the second
```

If you need any more help ask me.